# gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found

Tags: gnupg

I am trying to import the following key:

> https://www.apache.org/dist/pig/pig-0.16.0/pig-0.16.0.tar.gz.asc

Trying to import using:

```
gpg --import pig.sig
```

But getting the following error:

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

I have tried removing line breaks but the error is still there. How can fix it? I am interested in finding out the fingerprint.

Answer (score 1):

From the file name I read that what you try to import is not a key, but a signature on a file `pig-0.16.0.tar.gz`. You cannot import a signature, but verify it instead:

```
gpg --verify pig-0.16.0.tar.gz.asc
```

You need to fetch the key before verification. The required key ID will be printed when not found during verification, and can be fetched from key servers by running

```
gpg --recv-keys [key-id]
```

Be aware that if you don't validate the key against a trusted source, it could be issued by anybody. Key servers don't perform any verification, and an attacker could have just created a key using a fake name and mail address and issued the signature you just try to verify.

Comment: Basically I want to find out the id of the key and run gpg --keyserver <keyserver> -recv-keys. How can I find the key id from the ".asc" file?

Comment: Basically quoting my answer: "The required key ID will be printed when not found during verification".